# How to debug 406 HTTP response in client side JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, post, http-status-code-406

I am making a POST request from my web app to a local instance of elasticsearch. If I run the POST request with curl, I get an appropriate response:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search" -H'content-type: application/json' 

-d'{
  "highlight": {
    "fragment_size": 200,
    "number_of_fragments": 1,
    "fields": {
      "title": {},
      "description": {}
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "nps_link",
    "title",
    "description"
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "states": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "states.keyword",
        "size": 30
      }
    },
    "world_heritage_site": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "world_heritage_site"
      }
    },
    "visitors": {
      "range": {
        "field": "visitors",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 10000,
            "key": "0 - 10000"
          },
          {
            "from": 10001,
            "to": 100000,
            "key": "10001 - 100000"
          },
          {
            "from": 100001,
            "to": 500000,
            "key": "100001 - 500000"
          },
          {
            "from": 500001,
            "to": 1000000,
            "key": "500001 - 1000000"
          },
          {
            "from": 1000001,
            "to": 5000000,
            "key": "1000001 - 5000000"
          },
          {
            "from": 5000001,
            "to": 10000000,
            "key": "5000001 - 10000000"
          },
          {
            "from": 10000001,
            "key": "10000001+"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "acres": {
      "range": {
        "field": "acres",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": -1,
            "key": "Any"
          },
          {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 1000,
            "key": "Small"
          },
          {
            "from": 1001,
            "to": 100000,
            "key": "Medium"
          },
          {
            "from": 100001,
            "key": "Large"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20
}'
```

Yet, when I make the POST request using fetch, I get the error `POST http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search net::ERR_ABORTED 406 (Not Acceptable)`. How can I view the `Accept` header format that elastic search is responding with? For reference, my JS code is below:

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: can you remove the 'no-cors' mode and check? I think that is the problem.

Comment: The **Network** tab in the browser developers tools will show you both request and response headers.

Comment: If you add the `-v` option to your `curl` command it will give you more information about the headers, etc.  (I usually put it first so it doesn't get curl confused).

Comment: having `mode: no-cors` in a cross origin fetch guarantees that the response will not be readable by the client - however a 406 error seems unlikely, and is rarely seen in practice! see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)

Comment: Removing the `no-cors` parameter yields this error: ```Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9200/my-index/_search' from origin 'http://localhost:4444' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.```

Comment: It appears that the response comes with the following: ```content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 112
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8```, so I'm not sure why `application/json` is unreadable!

Comment: no-cors mode is not the answer to bypass cors check. you need to ensure that the service is returning the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response. Set this to your base url if security is a concern or * if not. either way the problem is with the service and not your code. remove 'no-cors' option.